# hose connection to sink drain broke. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, sink

A water softener drain hose is connected to a metal drain pipe of bathroom sink. I accidentally broke it and not sure what this part is called and how to properly attach it to the metal pipe.

As you can see from the picture, two small drain hoses are connected to sink drain, but one of them is broken. Is this something I can buy from HomeDepot? If so, how do I attach it to the pipe? Do I use something like epoxy glue to join the two metal parts together?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Should be able to get it at a big box hardware or plumbing store.  It looks to use an adhesive to join(maybe comes with part).   Will need to clean surface of pipe well.  Might need to use sandpaper(wet/dry)/file to remove old adhesive back to base metal.

Comment: @FreeMan  Have use similar type to tap into pressure lines(water), but they used U-bolts(muffler clamps) to hold on.

Comment: "Saddle valve", @crip659? Not highly recommended, as I understand it. As noted, _I've_ never seen a setup like this, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: @FreeMan  Do think that is the name for them.  Used them to hook up water bowls for the cows.  Imagine for drain system a simpler system would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That piece of drain pipe with **two** hose barbs looks like it was home-made.  Don't try to fix or replace it.  You can buy something similar:

[image]

The above part has the added benefit that water from the sink won't enter the filter hoses.

Or you could use *two* standard connectors for a single dishwasher.  You'll also have to replace the rest of the trap assembly with compatible PVC compression fit parts.

Disconnect the *entire* assembly between these two marked points:

[image]

take it whole to a good hardware or plumbing supply store and try to assemble something using products off the shelf that that does the job and will fit the same way when assembled.

While it is disassembled you should place a sandwich bag with a rubber band over the pipe coming out of the wall to avoid smells coming out of it.

Incidentally and while you are ducked under there, if you move the attachment point between the drain popup and its knob further away from the drain and probably to a lower hole, it should become easier to operate, and might seal better and drain better. Choose a hole that allows full travel and doesn't max out at either end.

[image]

Comment: +1! Oh, wait, too late... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you "broke" anything. To say this setup looks janky would be an understatement. My bet is they drilled a hole, shoved the brass connector in and caulked it up tight. It's a terrible way to do this and I suspect you proved why when whatever you did pulled the connector out. The brass probably wasn't holding anything in because it's meant to be an in-line hose connector with clamps outside the hoses it's connecting.

Normally, you use what's called an appliance wye for this. They come in chrome and PVC, and have the ribbed connector on the side. It looks like you need two, however. You might try buying two PVC wyes (they don't have a double-wye for these) and stacking them between your drain tailpiece and the P-trap (it would be tight but doable).

The other option is to buy a true double-wye and get two caps, then drill holes in the caps to feed the two drains through (can caulk it to reduce splashing if that becomes a problem).

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted how the parts fit together. The brass barb faced _outward_ and the two angled tabs secured the fitting into the tailpiece hole.

Comment: @isherwood You're right, that would make more sense. Still janky, but slightly less so, especially when you can buy pipes to do it without drilling holes in them.